# How to define a Typescript interface with hierarchy generic and other fields?

Tags: typescript, recursion, typescript-generics

What I want:

```js
type LocationBase<Level, LevelName, Child> = ...

type Region    = LocationBase<1, "region", Subregion>;
type Subregion = LocationBase<2, "subregion", Area>;
type Area      = LocationBase<3, "area">;
```

Which equivalent to:

```js
interface Region {
  level: 1;
  levelName: "region";
  children?: Subregion[];
}
interface Subregion {
  level: 2;
  levelName: "subregion";
  children?: Area[];
}
interface Area {
  level: 3;
  levelName: "area";
  children?: Location<4>;
}
interface Location<T extends number>{
  level: T;
  levelName: "location";
  children?: Location<PlusOne<T>>;
}
```

Is that possible?

---

I attempted with these code and there was some error:

> TS2716: Type parameter 'Child' has a circular default.

> TS2344: Type 'PlusOne<Level>' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'

```js
type ArrayWithLength<Len extends number, Arr extends never[] = []> = Arr["length"] extends Len ? Arr : ArrayWithLength<Len, [never, ...Arr]>;
type PlusOne<T extends number> = [unknown, ...ArrayWithLength<T>]["length"];

interface LocationBase<
  Level extends number = number,
  LevelName extends string = "location",
  Child = LocationBase, // Error
> {
  level: Level;
  levelName: LevelName;
  children?: Child[];
};

type Region = LocationBase<1, "region", Subregion>;
type Subregion = LocationBase<2, "subregion", Area>;
type Area = LocationBase<3, "area", LocationBase<4>>;

// type Level5ArrayExpected = LocationBase<4>["children"]; // unknown[]
```

Comment: Do you really want `children` to be optional in `Region` and `Subregion`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want `children` to be optional in `Region` and `Subregion`, you can give `Child` a default type of `undefined` (so you can leave it off when specifying `Area`) and have `LocationBase` define an intersection type in order to include or not include `children`:

```
type LocationBase<Level, LevelName, Child = undefined> =
    {
        level: Level;
        levelName: LevelName;
    } & (
        Child extends undefined ? {} : {children?: Child[]}
    );
```

Then your three example uses work just fine:

```
type Region    = LocationBase<1, "region", Subregion>;
//   ^? type Region = { level: 1; levelName: "region"; } & { children?: Subregion[] | undefined; }
type Subregion = LocationBase<2, "subregion", Area>;
//   ^? type Subregion = { level: 2; levelName: "subregion"; } & { children?: Area[] | undefined; }
type Area      = LocationBase<3, "area">;
//   ^? type Area = { level: 3; levelName: "area" }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIbAJZwHYCEkGcIA8MEAbhADYA0spFAckgLYTUDCAFquQCZQC8UAK4ZuEAGaoMEbgD5+AKChKoAb0XKN5WuQBcNMuQDc6jUq0GGzPcQtMIxjQF8oAMigAKE6Y5deEAB7AECK4QiLiktJQAPyqznoqCJw8AE7B0Xo+PADaALqOXgCUxvKgkFAAShAA5ugYGgLwyGiYOPgEAIzUAERptZjd1ADKggBGfXUyxgD008oAetGl4NAj4zV1-LCIKHVthABMPbhjEwPUAIJpSFPyswtLZdBXEEimW027rXiEAMw9SGu3Vu9yUi3kQA)

There are other ways to do it, but that's a fairly straightforward one.

You've shown `children` as optional on `Region` and `Subregion`, but if you wanted to require it, you'd just remove the `?` on it in the second half of the intersection, since we leave it out entirely on `Area`.

Comment: Thanks! I want children to be optional in `Region` and `Subregion` indeed. But I want Area has optional children as well (infinity cursive `Location`). Is that possible?

Comment: @GjfLeo - Probably. What type would you want `children` in `Area` to have?

Comment: I want `Area` has `children?: Location[]`, just like the second code block in question.

Comment: @GjfLeo - Sorry, I missed the *"Type 'PlusOne<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'."* part of your question, and I don't know how to solve it. `PlusOne<T>` *should* satisfy that constraint. It may be you're exceeding a limit in TypeScript, since if I replace it with `ArrayWithLength<T>["length"]` (which I know isn't the number you want), [it fails with an "excessive stack depth" issue](https://tsplay.dev/WzqBem). Since I can't solve that part, shall I remove the answer? (If it weren't for the `PlusOne` thing, adding `children` to `Area` wouldn't be hard.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you can retain it. :)